# SQL how to query two date windows in one table based on a date in another table optimally?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, getting both:

- the max value 5 days before the date in table_1 from the daily values in table_2
- the max value 5 days after the date in table_1 from the daily values in table_2

table1 (uid = id) - date windows are based off the date in this table

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2021-12-10 |
| b | 2021-12-21 |

table 2 (uid = id + date) - daily table

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-12-01 | 0 |
| a | 2021-12-02 | 3 |
| a | ... | ... |
| a | 2021-12-31 | 1 |
| b | 2021-12-01 | 4 |
| b | ... | ... |
| b | 2021-12-31 | 0 |

output table (uid = id)

| id | date | start_dt_before | end_dt_before | max_value_before | start_dt_after | end_dt_after | max_value_after |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-12-10 | 2021-12-05 | 2021-12-09 | 3 | 2021-12-10 | 2021-12-14 | 4 |
| b | 2021-12-21 | 2021-12-16 | 2021-12-20 | 2 | 2021-12-21 | 2021-12-25 | 5 |

Querying one of the tables twice in two seperate joins seems to be very resource intensive. Is there a way to more optimally query this in a single query?

EDIT -- added example code per request

```sql
-- Create table_1
CREATE TABLE table_1 (id CHAR(1), event_dt DATE);
INSERT INTO table_1 (id,event_dt) VALUES ('a','2021-12-10');
INSERT INTO table_1 (id,event_dt) VALUES ('b','2021-12-21');


-- Create table_2

CREATE TABLE table_2 (id CHAR(1), day_dt DATE, value INT);

INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-01',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-02',3);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-03',7);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-04',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-05',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-06',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-07',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-08',3);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-09',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-10',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-11',4);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-12',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-13',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-14',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-15',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-16',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-17',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-18',9);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-19',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-20',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-21',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-22',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-23',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-24',9);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-25',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-26',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-27',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-28',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-29',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-30',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('a','2021-12-31',1);

INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-01',4);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-02',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-03',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-04',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-05',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-06',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-07',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-08',9);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-09',9);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-10',9);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-11',9);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-12',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-13',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-14',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-15',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-16',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-17',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-18',2);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-19',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-20',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-21',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-22',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-23',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-24',5);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-25',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-26',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-27',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-28',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-29',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-30',0);
INSERT INTO table_2 (id,day_dt,value) VALUES ('b','2021-12-31',0);


-- Example queries that creates desired output:

SELECT
    x.id
    , x.event_dt
    , x.before_min_dt
    , x.before_max_dt
    , x.before_value
    , MIN(t2.day_dt) after_min_dt
    , MAX(t2.day_dt) after_max_dt
    , MAX(t2.value) after_value
FROM(
SELECT
    t1.id
    , t1.event_dt
    , MIN(t2.day_dt) before_min_dt
    , MAX(t2.day_dt) before_max_dt
    , MAX(t2.value) before_value
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2
ON (t1.id = t2.id 
    AND t2.day_dt >= DATE_ADD(t1.event_dt, INTERVAL -5 DAY) 
    AND t2.day_dt < t1.event_dt)
GROUP BY 
    t1.id
    , t1.event_dt
) x
JOIN table_2 t2
ON (x.id = t2.id 
    AND t2.day_dt >= x.event_dt 
    AND t2.day_dt < DATE_ADD(x.event_dt, INTERVAL 5 DAY))
GROUP BY     
    x.id
    , x.event_dt
    , x.before_min_dt
    , x.before_max_dt
    , x.before_value;
```

Comment: One join then 2 window functions with separate window definitions.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? And what about the exact date e.g. `2021-12-10`... is it included in the -5 days or +5 days?

Comment: @Akina that sounds ideal, can you show an example? Thanks

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO formatted codes, and desired table-formatted output for this data strictly.

Comment: @Akina Thanks, I've added the scripts for the sample data and an example query that generates the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT table_2.id,
       table_1.event_dt, 
       table_1.event_dt - INTERVAL 5 DAY before_min_dt,
       table_1.event_dt - INTERVAL 1 DAY before_max_dt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN table_2.day_dt BETWEEN table_1.event_dt - INTERVAL 5 DAY
                                        AND table_1.event_dt - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                THEN value
                END) max_value_before,
       table_1.event_dt after_min_dt,
       table_1.event_dt + INTERVAL 4 DAY after_max_dt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN table_2.day_dt BETWEEN table_1.event_dt
                                        AND table_1.event_dt + INTERVAL 4 DAY
                THEN value
                END) max_value_after
FROM table_1
JOIN table_2 ON table_2.id = table_1.id
            AND table_2.day_dt BETWEEN table_1.event_dt - INTERVAL 5 DAY
                                   AND table_1.event_dt + INTERVAL 4 DAY
GROUP BY table_1.event_dt, table_2.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ffda56d3e03e64b8891d438a68a5bbc2